# UITableView cellForRow(at:) crashes randomly while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a requirement to show border around user's avatar image but only for the user cell at center of table. Also, the border width is proportional to its distance from center.

So I've my cell update logic in `UIScrollView` delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll` API and then get the middle cell using `UITableView` `contentOffset.y`. Once I know the center point of table I ask the table to give me cell at that point and then updating its value.

However, the call to `tableView.cellForRow(at:)` **randomly** throws an exception and crashes. I do guard for `nil` value but don't know how to handle this crash due to exception.

Also, note `centerLevelCellIndexPath` value looks good to me when that exception is raised - section 0 row 3 ( My UITableView always have 1 section and about 5-6 rows)

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  if scrollView is UITableView {
    let tableViewCenterContentOffset = CGPoint(x: tableView.center.x, y: tableView.contentOffset.y + tableView.bounds.height/2)
    guard let centerLevelCellIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tableViewCenterContentOffset) else {
        return
    }
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: centerLevelCellIndexPath),      // <--- Crashes here
        let centerLevelCell =  cell as? MyCustomCell,
        let collectionView = centerLevelCell.collectionView else {
            return
    }
```

Here is the screenshot of exception call stack -

[image]

Comment: What exactly the error says?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was `objectAtIndex` exception inside that cellForRow API. It's extremely hard to reproduce (random) so I will post the call stack (screenshot) next time I reproduce it.

Comment: Added the screenshot of exception call stack @TusharSharma